# Clean or Filter Data

Tags: spark-streaming, flume

I 'm using spark streaming where in I'm using Flume receiver.

The streamed events consist of many fields that I do not require. So, I want to filter this out.

I just want to check which is better place to filter data:

- Applying a flume interceptor to alter data and then giving it to spark or, streaming.
- Applying filtering on DStream in Spark Streaming.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both the options will work. Depending on two things you can decide -

1. Flume interceptor is more decoupled way of doing it.
2. Spark streaming will be faster.

If you are receiving numerous event per second than I would say go for spark streaming and if thats not the case, go for flume interceptors.